# Counting days of the week in Excel for multiple locations and sub-groups without manual expansion

Tags: excel, pivot-table

In excel I have hundreds of rows locations. Each location has a sub-group with the days of the week that the location is visited. I need to count the days of the week for each location and still be able to expand/collapse each sub-group without interfering with the count.

Example:

```
1
   Sunday
2
   Monday
   Wednesday
3
   Thursday
4
   Monday
   Wednesday
   Friday
**5**
**6**
**7**
```

Correct Count: 1 is 1, 2 is 2, 3 is 1, and 4 is 3.

It's important to be able to count each group without having to open each group because there are hundreds of them.

Thank you

I tried COUNT and COUNTIF but the problem I'm running into is that each group would have to be expanded for the count to work.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the Excel sheet - including how your expected result would look like.